# Посл запуска виндовс сразу синий кран

Tags: windows

После запуска виндовс вылазит такой синий экран что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: отладку через загрузочный диск

Comment: Пробывал Даже жесткий диск менял на котором другая винда но проблема та же

Comment: восстановление с контрольной точки?

Comment: может поможет https://youtu.be/pejg7Y3IE2Y

Comment: http://lifehacki.ru/windows-comstopcode-kak-reshit/

Comment: Как я это сделаю, если винда не работает?

Comment: там еще белые полоски, которых в обычных экранах смерти нет

Comment: у тебя вообще не включается что-ли после перезагрузки?

Comment: Включатся , но после 1-10 сек синий экран

Comment: Проблема явно не с виндой, т.к подключал друго жесткий диск с другой виндой и проблема та же

Comment: тогда значит проблема в видеокарте

Comment: попробуй включить комп через Լive CD Ubuntu

Comment: может вопрос в работе Windows-а и видео-карты

Comment: Проблема точно не в ОС

Comment: @Sasha пробовали зайти в безопасный режим? или не получилось?